# Asynchronous promise queue with duplicate protection and error handling

Tags: javascript

**Context:** I'd like to create some kind of simple framework that allows me to queue `action`'s, which are named `sequence`'s of asynchronous tasks. If an `action` is already in the queue, it shouldn't be re-queued until the current `action` is complete. If an `action` has an error, it should call some handling function, then proceed to the next `action` in the queue.

So it seems like using promises is the way to go, and my initial solution uses a `queue` property that chains promises and stores action names.

**Code:**

```
var someGlobal = {
    queue: {
        _queue: Array(),
        _tasks: Promise.resolve(),
        push: function(action) {
                if (this.is_queued(action.name))
                    return
                this._queue.push(action.name)
                action.sequence.forEach((item) => {
                        this._tasks = this._tasks.then(item)
                })
                this._tasks = this._tasks.catch(action.err_handler)
                this._tasks = this._tasks.then(() => {
                        this._queue.shift()
                })
        },
        is_queued: function(action) {
                return this._queue.includes(action)
        }
    },
    aFunctionThatPushes: function() {
            this.queue.push({
                    name: "someaction",
                    sequence: [
                            () => this.promiseReturningFunction1(someArgs).bind(this),
                            () => this.promiseReturningFunction2(someArgs).bind(this),
                            () => this.promiseReturningFunction3(someArgs).bind(this)
                    ],
                    err_handler: (error) => {
                            console.log(error.getMessage())
                    }
            })
    }
}
```

(Untested, so if there's something syntactically wrong, ignore it for the sake of architecture)

**Concerns:**

I'm mainly worried about two things. The first is that `queue._tasks` is going to be a promise chain that keeps growing and growing, so it seems that memory usage will continue to get bigger and bigger.

Second, is that the syntax of pushing an `action` is somewhat cumbersome. It's not a huge deal for three `task`'s, but for a very long `sequence`, it'll get annoying to include the `() =>` and `.bind(this)` every time.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to avoid wrapping my promise returning functions in another function?

Comment: I could change my `promiseReturningFuction#()` to return a function itself, but sometimes they are used internally to chain promises i.e. `promiseReturningFunction2: function() { return this.promiseReturningFunction1(someArgs).then(() => { //stuff })}` so I'd have to add `()`'s everytime they're used internally.

Comment: If your queue is being pushed faster than it's being processed, then yes it will grow. There's not much you can do about that other than throw an error once you reach a certain boundary and more actions are attempted to be pushed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm not worried about that because there are a fixed number of `action`s, so there's a limit. But won't memory usage grow because there's a huge chain of resolved promises? Or do they get gc'ed out of memory after resolution?

Comment: they're GC'd after resolution, assuming you're not accidentally keeping references to them anywhere else.